# Derivation of composite bayesian posterior

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

In [Trifonov et al. (2013)](https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1752-0509-7-25), which uses a bayesian framework to identify prioritized gene lesions, a composite posterior is defined as:

$$P(D|S) \quad \underline{deff} \quad \sum_{i}P(D|M_i) \cdot P(M_i|S) \tag{1}$$

I am trying to derive this posterior from the simple posteriors defined previously in the article, i.e.:

$$P(D|M)= \frac{\delta(D \in M) \cdot P^d(D)}{\sum_{G∈M}P^d(G)}\tag{2}$$

$$P(M|S)= \frac{\delta(M \in S)\cdot P^d(M)}{\sum_{j}P^d(M_j)}\tag{3}$$

My derivation is the following:

$$P(D|S) \quad \underline{deff} \quad \sum_{i}P(D|M_i)·P(M_i|S)\tag{4}$$

Inserting the actual posteriors:

$$P(D|S)= \sum_{i} \frac{\delta(D \in M_i) \cdot P^d(D)}{\sum_{G \in M_i} P^d(G)} \cdot \frac{\delta(M \in S) \cdot P^d(M_i)}{\sum_{j} P^d(M_j)}\tag{5}$$

If $D \in M_i$ then $D \in \bigcup S$ because $M_i \in S$, then:

$$P(D|S) = (\delta(D \in \bigcup S) \cdot P^d(D)) \cdot \sum_{i} \frac{ P^d(M_i)}{\sum_{G \in M_i} P^d(G) \cdot \sum_{j} P^d(M_j)}\tag{6}$$

Same as the previous step, since $M_i \in S$ the first sum at the denominator can be defined with respect to $\bigcup S$:

$$P(D|S) = \frac{\delta(D \in \bigcup S) \cdot P^d(D)}{\sum_{G \in \bigcup S} P^d(G)} \sum_{i} \frac{P^d(M_i)}{\sum_{j} P^d(M_j)}\tag{7}$$

At this point I'm stuck. The original article continues:

> To obtain the global posterior $P^g(D|S)$ we assume that $P^d(M) \propto \sum_{G \in M} P^d(G)$ in which case:
>   $$P^g(D|S) = \frac{\delta(D \in \bigcup S) \cdot P^d(D)}{\sum_{G \in \bigcup S} P^d(G)}\tag{8}$$

What is the passage that lead to the elimination of $\sum_{i} \frac{P^d(M_i)}{\sum_{j} P^d(M_j)}$?

Comment: This is reminiscent of inserting the sum of orthonormal wave function outer products into a bra-ket pair as a form of identity operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually simple. The elimination of $\sum_{i}\frac{P^d(M_i)}{\sum_{j}P^d(M_j)}$ is straightforward once you see that both the numerator and denominator are the sum of the same elements.